# how to creae inbox next to viewing message

Tags: php

i have just created a message system but i would like to show the inbox next to the message being viewed like facebook messaging system does but i can get it to work next to each other i have to do it though links so the inbox is viewed on index.php and to view message you have to go to index.php?hash=VAULE how do i get them to work side by side as facebook does

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['hash']) && !empty($_GET['hash'])){
$hash = $_GET['hash'];
$message_query= mysql_query("SELECT from_id, message FROM messages WHERE group_hash='$hash'");
while($run_message = mysql_fetch_array($message_query)){
    $from_id = $run_message['from_id'];
    $message = $run_message['message'];
        $staff_query = mysql_query("SELECT staff_username FROM staff_users WHERE id='$from_id'");
        $run_staff = mysql_fetch_array($staff_query);
        $from_staff = $run_staff['staff_username'];
            echo "<p><b>$from_staff</b><br/>$message</p>";
}
?>
<br/>
<form method='POST'>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['message']) && !empty($_POST['message'])){
        $new_message = $_POST['message'];
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO messages VALUES('','$hash','$my_id','$new_message')");
        header('location: index.php?hash='.$hash);
  }
  ?>
<div class="message_box">
Enter Message : <br/>
<textarea name='message' placeholder="Write a reply" rows='6' cols="60"></textarea>
<br/>
<input type='submit' name="smb" value="Reply"/>
</form>
</div>
<?php
}else{
$get_con = mysql_query("SELECT hash, staff_one, staff_two FROM messages_hash WHERE staff_one='$my_id' OR staff_two='$my_id'");
while($run_con = mysql_fetch_array($get_con)){
    $hash = $run_con['hash'];
    $staff_one = $run_con['staff_one'];
    $staff_two = $run_con['staff_two'];
    if($staff_one == $my_id){
        $select_id = $staff_two;
    }else{
        $select_id = $staff_one;
    }
    $staff_get = mysql_query("SELECT staff_username FROM staff_users WHERE id='$select_id'");
    $run_staff = mysql_fetch_array($staff_get);
    $select_staff = $run_staff['staff_username'];
    echo "<p><a href='index.php?hash=$hash'>$select_staff</a></p>";
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create two files. One that pulls the inbox and one that pulls the current message.

Then include them individually inside your code where you want them to appear.

Comment: how would i i do this as when you click the name it sends you to index.php?hash=value how would i make it appear on the same page a as using location will send it to a different page and i dont know how to this